# AppleScript Count and Remove Characters in Excel

Tags: excel, count, applescript

I am having issues with my applescript that removes any filename that is greater than 13 characters long. I have a list of filenames in column B and I only need the ones that are 13 characters, nothing more than. I am looking for the script to delete the row of anything more than 13. So far this has been somewhat working and but not removing all of them.

```
        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        open (choose file with prompt "Select the Excel file you wish to use.")
    end tell


    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        tell active sheet
            autofit column "A:H"
        end tell
    end tell

set cellNumber to 2

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        repeat
            set fileName to get value of cell ("B" & cellNumber) as string
            set fncount to count characters of fileName
            if fncount is greater than 13 then
                delete entire row of cell ("B" & cellNumber)
                set endCount to 0
            else
                set endCount to endCount + 1
                if endCount > 100 then
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end if
            set cellNumber to cellNumber + 1
        end repeat
    end tell
    set endCount to 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not delete everything, because when the script delete a row, **Excel** will shift the rows up.

> **Example**: the script delete the second row, now the second row is
>   the third row, so the script skip a row

To avoid that, the loop must start at the index of the last row.

Use the `used range` property to get the last row.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open (choose file with prompt "Select the Excel file you wish to use.")
    tell active sheet
        set cellNumber to 2
        autofit column "A:H"
        set lastR to count rows of used range -- get the index of the last row which contains a value
        repeat with i from lastR to cellNumber by -1 --  iterates backwards from the index of the last row 
            set fileName to string value of cell ("B" & i)
            if (count fileName) > 13 then delete row i
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```